# Form not submitting using the validationEngine() plugin from Position Absolute

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using the validationEngine jQuery plugin to validate my webform. Once the validation completes, I'd like to submit the form via ajax. The form submits fine without the validation engine plugin attached. The validation works, but the ajax is not firing to submit the form after it completes. What am I doing wrong:

```
jQuery("form#sign-up").validationEngine({
    onValidationComplete: function () {
        var first = $("input#first").val();
        var last = $("input#last").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var pass = $("input#pass").val();



        var dataString = 'first=' + first + '&last=' + last + '&email=' + email + '&pass=' + pass;

        //to send the ajax request  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./register.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                $('#sign-up').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>Thanks!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>We'll send you an email when infoFree is ready to Rock n' Roll.</p>")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(500, function () {
                    $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='./assets/images/check.png' />");
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

validationengine prevents the form actually submitting, so instead of doing everything inside onValidationComplete, just move it all into a function on submit of the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form#sign-up").validationEngine();
  $("form#sign-up").submit(function(){
    var first = $("input#first").val();
    var last = $("input#last").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var pass = $("input#pass").val();

    var dataString = 'first='+ first + '&last=' + last + '&email=' + email + '&pass=' + pass;

    //to send the ajax request  
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./register.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#sign-up').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Thanks!</h2>")
        .append("<p>We'll send you an email when infoFree is ready to Rock n' Roll.</p>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(500, function() {
          $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='./assets/images/check.png' />");
        });
      } 
    });
  });
}); // ready
```

~Cyrix